# searchview not gain focus but keyboard opens

Tags: android, searchview, android-searchmanager

i m using searchview for search functionality my problem is that when i click on search icon keyboard gets opened but searchview does not get focus below is my code

**menu.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/send_invitation"
            android:icon="@drawable/send_icon_invite_participant"
            android:orderInCategory="93"
            android:title="@string/invitation"
            app:showAsAction="always">
        </item>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
            android:icon="@drawable/search_icn"
            android:title="@string/search"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

below is code from method

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.invite_participant, menu);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    searchItem.expandActionView();
    ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
    searchIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.search_icn);
    ImageView searchCloseIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
    searchCloseIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.reject_icon_notification);
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(activity.getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setItemsVisibility(menu, searchItem, false);
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                searchView.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (adapter != null) {
                    adapter.fliter(newText);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                setItemsVisibility(menu, searchItem, true);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}

private void setItemsVisibility(Menu menu, MenuItem exception, boolean visible) {
    for (int i=0; i<menu.size(); ++i) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        if (item != exception) item.setVisible(visible);
    }
}
```

i m not able to find why it does not get focused please help me in finding where i have done mistake any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can add these lines for focus with searchview.

```
 searchView.setFocusable(true);
    searchView.requestFocus();
    searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

If it'll not work then First expand search view then request for focus.

Comment: thank u so much for your response at where I should add this line

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it either by adding below code in  your Activity's `onCreate` method.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

or by adding this line in your AndroidManifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

**Edit:**

Try something like this

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: unfortunately this is a fragment class

Comment: @ Mr 7 i solve it by changing order in category value